# How to pass data from parent component to child after creation of child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically, I am building a trivia game with React and I am still learning so need some suggestions on how to achieve my goal here. I have 2 component, `question.jsx` which is the parent component keeping the game state
`state = {
        currentQuestion: {},
        questions: [],
        dataFetched: false
}`

and `answerBox.jsx` which is the child component simply rendering multiple choice answers to the given question as 2x2 grid style. So what I want to achieve here is in the child component when I select an answer

1- Send the selected answer to the parent class to check if it is correct

2- Mark the answer as chosen for a period of time and then mark it to green if correct and red if false

So what I am currently doing is, passing an `onClick` function to the child so when the answer is chosen I am able to check it in my parent component. So this is where I got stuck, after checking the answer in my parent class how can I pass to the child component if the chosen answer is true or false? Maybe I am overthinking something here but an explanation for my problem here would be great, maybe I need to change my component design so the check should be done in the child component instead?

Comment: can you post the code for the components?  will be easier to see what's going on and how your onClick function is handled and what it is doing exactly

Comment: You pass it down via props.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `question` component owns the state it should tell the child components what they should render, something along the lines of:

```
<AnswerBox data={data} answerIsCorrect={true} />
```

Where `data` is the current data you pass to the component. The child component can check if the prop `answerIsCorrect` was passed and what is it's value.

So for a wrong answer it would like this:

```
<AnswerBox data={data} answerIsCorrect={false} />
```

and if not answered yet:

```
<AnswerBox data={data} />
```

This is just to show one approach of addressing this, the main point here is that the child component should only concern itself with rendering and sending back user actions to the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

You need the parent component to re-render. Call this.setState() for this and pass the Boolean value down to the child.

Answer (score 0):

this will depend on your overall code architecture, but you just need to store the answer result somewhere in state and pass that state down to the child component. When you update that part of the state in the parent, the child will also be updated, something along these lines:

```
class Parent {
  state = {
    answerResults: {},
    questions: [],
  };

  checkAnswer = (question) => {
      const result = checkIfTrueOrFalse();
      const { answerResults } = this.state;
      answerResults[questionId] = result;

      this.setState({ answerResults });
  };

  render() {
    const { answerResults, questions } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
       { 
         questions.map(q => (
           <AnswerBox 
             answerResult={answerResults[q.id]} 
             checkAnswer={this.checkAnswer} 
           />
          ) 
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class AnswerBox {
    render() {
        const { answerResult, checkAnswer } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                { answerResult }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```